# Spinner adapter with dynamic textViews

Tags: android

I've got question about spinner. I've got arrayAdapter and it looks like this :

```
ArrayAdapter<FilterData> filters = new ArrayAdapter<FilterData>(
                    this, R.layout.filter_spinner_style, sessionPreferences
                    .getSelectedMenuButton().getItemData().getFilters()) {

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                    ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    ((TextView) v).setTypeface(mFontSemiBold);

                    return v;
                }

                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(final int position, View convertView,
                                            ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,
                            parent);

                    ((TextView) v).setTypeface(mFontSemiBold);
                    ((TextView) v).setTextSize(10);
                    ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_blue));


                    return v;

                }
            };
            filters.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`enter code here`
            spinner.setAdapter(filters);
```

It's filled with FilterData objects. However every FilterData object has also List - FilterItemList inside. Here my question - is it possible to display in the spinner DropDownView also FilterItemList? I tried to do it with onClick like this :

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView v = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        FilterData data = getItem(position);
        List<FilterItem> filterItemList = data.getFilterItemList();
        for(FilterItem filterItem : filterItemList) {
            v.setText(filterItem.getFilterItemName());
        }

        return v;
    }
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions ? :)

Comment: Please add the code which you tried .

Comment: " tried to do it with onClick like this :"  Where is this code ?

Comment: don't you see the code beneath? I added it.